# ASPNET Docker image: Updating authentication using powershell stops W3SVC

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Trying to update IIS authentication settings using Powershell.
Here's the dockerfile:

`FROM microsoft/aspnet`

`SHELL ["powershell"]`

`WORKDIR C:\MyWebApp`

`` RUN Import-Module WebAdministration; ` ``
`` New-WebApplication -Name 'MyWebApp' -Site 'Default Web Site' -PhysicalPath C:\MyWebApp -ApplicationPool DefaultAppPool; ` ``

```
    Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter "/system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication" -Name Enabled -Value False -PSPath IIS:\ -Location "'Default Web Site/MyWebApp'"; `
    Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter "/system.webServer/security/authentication/basicAuthentication" -Name Enabled -Value False -PSPath IIS:\ -Location "'Default Web Site/MyWebApp'"; `
    Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter "/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication" -Name Enabled -Value True -PSPath IIS:\ -Location "'Default Web Site/MyWebApp'"; `
    Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter "/system.web/identity" -Name impersonate -Value True -PSPath IIS:\ -Location "'Default Web Site/MyWebApp'"; `
    Set-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool\ -Name managedPipelineMode -Value 0; `
    Set-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool\ -Name enable32BitAppOnWin64 -Value True;
```

Set-WebConfigurationProperty is causing W3SVC to get stopped and container exits.

```
PS C:\Projects\docker_workspace\app> docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                   CREATED              STATUS                               PORTS
96bc3c60e9df        wcpapp:v1           "C:\\ServiceMonitor.e…"   About a minute ago   Exited (2147500037) 12 seconds ago

PS C:\Projects\docker_workspace\app> docker logs 96

 Service 'w3svc' has been stopped

ERROR: Failed to start or query status of service 'w3svc' error [80004005]

 Service 'w3svc' has been stopped
```

If I remove Set-WebConfigurationProperty statements, Container stays up and running. What am I missing here?